# Editing previous graph after plotting multiple R graphs

Tags: r, graph

I plotted two graphs:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # 2 graphs, positioning them side by side

a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(3,6,4)
c<-c(2,5,5)
d<-c(3,4,5)

plot(a,b)  #1st graph
plot(c,d)  #2nd graph
```

Say now I want to add a point to the 1st graph (i.e. the graph on the left),

```
points(2.5,4.5)
```

how can I do this without restarting the plot again?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't.  Base plotting uses a pen and paper model.  Once you start a new plot, the previous plot is no longer available as an object.  This contrasts with the philosophy used in `lattice` and `ggplot2`.

Comment: Can't you just plot in different order? i.e. `plot(a,b); points(2.5,4.5); plot(c,d)`

Comment: I can't really.  Basically I am writing a loop and it involves plotting different things on different graphs...

Comment: @Andrie pen and paper means no eraser, but you're still able to draw on top. What's important here is the access to plot coordinates (viewport in grid parlance), which par(mfg can provide.

Answer (score 2):

par(mfg) can get you there,

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(0,0,0,0))

plot.new()
grid()
box()
plot.new()
grid()
box()
points(0.5,0.5, col="red")
par(mfg=c(1,1))
points(0.5,0.5, col="blue")
par(mfg=c(2,1))
points(0.5,0.5, col="red", pch="+")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something has to be carried around. In this case I think it's the underlying data (a,b,c,d).  Try

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(3,6,4)
c<-c(2,5,5)
d<-c(3,4,5)

myPlot <- function(){
    par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # 2 graphs, positioning them side by side
    plot(a,b)  #1st graph
    plot(c,d)  #2nd graph
}

myPlot()
a <- cbind(a,2.5)
b <- cbind(b,4.5)
myPlot()
```